# How do I fix the error "The type or namespace name RigidBody could not be found"?

Tags: unity, c#

I got stuck with this problem; I have searched Unity forums but could not get an answer to solve it.

I am getting this error:

> The type or namespace name RigidBody could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playercomponent : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public RigidBody rb;
    
    void start()
    {
        this.rb =  GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal,0.0f,moveVertical);
        
        rb.AddForce(movement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it should be Rigidbody, not RigidBody

Comment: thanks @Leggy but in default suggestions it shows RigidBody ?? what is that

Comment: what does suggest you RigidBody by default? in Monodevelop?

Comment: yes ,it shows "RigidBody" with capital "B" when we write something in unity, default suggestions

Comment: Still helpful in 2021. Such a silly mistake.